# IntelliJ Database explorer won't work with localhost Mongo 4.4.3

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm up-the-middle MongoDB with authentication localhost. I have the mongod configured to bind a specific user to a specific database and from the mongo shell and my Java programs, everything works great. When I log in as that user I can do all the mongo stuff on the mongo db I bound that user to.

```
$ mongo -u totallyLegitUser --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("2ba7a3f6-2ca1-49b7-8241-8133ceb3d842") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.3
> use mfg-plan;
switched to db mfg-plan
> show collections;
activity
...
```

When I try to set up the same user through IntelliJ's "Database" thing, the "Test Connection" says everything is fine, but I can't run any queries through the console and the "explorer" drop down thing doesn't show collections I know are in the database.

This is what shows up when I look in the console after I've try to run the db.activity.findOne(); from the cli session...

```
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256, userName='totallyLegitUser', source='mfg-plan', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>} com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 17 (ProtocolError): 'Attempt to switch database target during SASL authentication.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Attempt to switch database target during SASL authentication.", "code": 17, "codeName": "ProtocolError"}
```

I have confirmed that the username, password, and database are all correct.

[image]

How do I get IntelliJ to connect to my authenticating mongos?

Comment: have you specified target db in 'Database' field of connection settings? Your URL in  IDE should look like mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?dbName&authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb.

Comment: @YuriWin I have, yes. That makes the error message even more strange, though. The URL there isn't the URL when I "cut and paste" from the "Properties" dialog: mongodb://localhost:27017/mfg-plan. Hmmm.

Comment: @YuriWin AH. Thats the clue. In the properties of the Database connection, it is expecting what the commandline would call the autheticationDatabase (usually admin). I was giving it the database what has the documents I'm trying to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. In the "Data Sources and Drivers" dialog for my mongo hosts it asks for a Database. I was giving it the database I wanted to connect to on the host (mfg-plan). What it wants is the authenticationDatabase for the host (usually 'admin'). When I change that to 'admin', all is well.

[image]